# How do I check data gaussianity with excel?

Tags: excel

Well, I have a data set (length 20) and I want to check its gaussianity or non-gaussianity. I'm an somewhat advanced user of matlab so I already know (it doesn't fit a gaussian) but I have to prove it with excel and I have never used its statistical tools very much. What's the best way to do it?

EDIT: I had several ideas, but none of those appear to be practical in excel. First, I thought it would be a fitting tool (something like matlab's `histfit`) but I didn't find it. Second, I thought I could say my data is approximate gaussian if the deciles of my data set are the approximate the same of the gaussian distribution with mean=dataSetMean and variance=dataSetVariance, but excel doesn't have any of those.

Comment: While this is a good question, can you show a bit of previous attempts at getting it to work? Also I don't think it belongs to StackOverflow because it's not a direct programming-related question.

Comment: Hi @Jerrybibo. I just updated my question with my attempts, and about the site, if you point me to the right one, I'll post there. Thanks

Comment: I was thinking of Super User, but this is probably a better fit. Never mind.

Comment: Do you have any ideas? Or something that could help, given my attempts?